# HQL Queries rounds off numbers

Tags: grails, groovy, hql

I have built a grails application and am using HQL in my controller to pass parameters to my "index.gsp" using g-select tags. There is a very simple issue I am facing, when the value comes to the front-end (browser/client side), the numbers are rounded off.

I was not facing this before while using SQL in my controller, but now since my index.gsp and controller are communicating using "params" and g select, HQL had to be used and this rounds off all numbers (basic metrics, calculated metrics etc)

Query example (controller) :

In this query, I am taking revenue, it's YoY and WoW from my backend table and even this is rounded off ( all values shown in visualization)

```
def com = Com.executeQuery("
        SELECT p.date_hour
            ,p.total_revenue
            ,CASE 
                WHEN total_revenue_ly IN (
                        0
                        ,NULL
                        )
                    THEN 0
                ELSE ((total_revenue / total_revenue_ly - 1) * 100)
                END AS yoy
            ,CASE 
                WHEN total_revenue_lw IN (
                        0
                        ,NULL
                        )
                    THEN 0
                ELSE ((total_revenue / total_revenue_lw - 1) * 100)
                END AS wow
        FROM Com p
        WHERE p.department = ?
            AND p.device = ?
            AND p.browser = ?
            AND p.platform = ?
            AND p.mv = ?
            AND p.time_period = ?
        ORDER BY col_0_0_ ASC",
   [params.department, params.device, params.browser, 
   params.platform, params.mv, params.time_period])
   render com as JSON
```

I also have to write queries for "conversion rate" etc(calculated metrics) :

```
def com = Tablev1.executeQuery("
        SELECT p.date_hour
            ,CASE 
                WHEN visits IN ((0,NULL)
                    THEN 0
                ELSE ((p.orders / p.visits) * 100)
                END AS metric
            ,CASE 
                WHEN visits IN ((0,NULL)
                    THEN 0
                WHEN orders_ly IN ((0,NULL)
                    THEN 0
                WHEN visits_ly IN ((0,NULL)
                    THEN 0
                ELSE ((((orders / visits) / (orders_ly / visits_ly)) - 1) * 100)
                END AS yoy
            ,CASE 
                WHEN visits IN ((0,NULL)
                    THEN 0
                WHEN orders_lw IN ((0,NULL)
                    THEN 0
                WHEN visits_lw IN ((0,NULL)
                    THEN 0
                ELSE ((((orders / visits) / (orders_lw / visits_lw)) - 1) * 100)
                END AS wow
        FROM Tablev1 p
        WHERE p.platform = ?
            AND p.mv = ?
            AND p.time_period = ?
        ORDER BY col_0_0_ ASC",

[params.platform, params.mv, params.time_period])
            render com as JSON
```

Even these values are rounded off. I am displaying the values in the console of browser and in the array only they are rounded off, my visualization is a graph using highcharts.js but I don't think there is an issue with highcharts.js as the array feeded to highcharts is only rounded off.
The data type of revenue in first query was also float, but still it's rounded off.
The problem lies in HQL or index-controller communication

In a different application, using case when rounds off numbers and not using case when displays the decimals, I don't understand this. Can someone pls explain it?

How do I resolve this issue?
Any approches/suggestions are most welcome.

UPDATE:

Ignore the entire case when, a simple query like this also is passing rounded values

```
def com = Com.executeQuery("
            SELECT p.date_hour
                ,p.total_revenue
            FROM Com p
            WHERE p.department = ?
                AND p.device = ?
                AND p.browser = ?
                AND p.platform = ?
                AND p.mv = ?
                AND p.time_period = ?
            ORDER BY col_0_0_ ASC",
       [params.department, params.device, params.browser, 
       params.platform, params.mv, params.time_period])
       render com as JSON
```

Comment: Do you have a sample query which works properly when not using CASE? I am not sure I understand the problem correctly.

Comment: @carbontax , check updated answer. The controller is passing rounded values even though it's datatype is float and the value in back end is a decimal! Can I somehow print values picked in controller on console an debug in grails?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a float value when multiplying:

```
... ELSE ((total_revenue / total_revenue_ly - 1) * 100.0)
```

Comment: Tried, not working . I tried for the simple metric : (total_revenue * 1.00 ) and also the same example you provided, neither are working. Any other workaround?

Comment: hey, it worked for metrics, but wherever we have used case when, it's not working. Can you tell another way for case-when statements?

Comment: Your example does not show this, which is why I asked. Your query without case statements does not include a calculation where you multiply a float value and an integer value.